# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am making simple windows form application with visual studio 2012. I created local database. I created in database table called *"gerimai"* and `2` columns called *"cola"*, *"fanta"*.

Then I created `comboBox1` and `button1` in design.

I want that when I press `button1`, my `comboBox1` would fill with *"cola"* column members.

Here is my 5th time modified code.

What I am doing wrong? Can anyone show me how to do this with dataset too?

> Connection string : "Data Source=D:\test\lolc\lolc\Database1.sdf";
>   Provider :.NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server
>   Compact 4.0; state : Closed; type : Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact;
>   Version : 4.0.8876.1;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=D:\test\lolc\lolc\Database1.sdf");
    Con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select cola from gerimai", Con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "cola";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "cola";
}
```

I am getting this error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified).

I can do everything in design view where wizards are doing hard work, but i wanna do it programmatically..

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is the combo box empty? Are you getting an error?

Comment: whats error exeptions?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified). If i do with wizard at design view. It works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

1st is your `SQL QUERY` is selecting only `cola` column change it to `*` if you want to select all columns
Next, Following code will display Text & has Value both of cola-column data

```
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "cola";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "cola";
```

Now, This will display Text of Cola members and has Value of Fanta members

```
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "cola";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "fanta";
```

U can get values as --

```
comboBox1.selectedValue();
comboBox1.selectedText();
```

But WHAT EXACTLY YOU WANT ???

Comment: I am getting this error always. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified). I can do everything in design view where wizards are doing hard work, but i wanna do it programmatically..

Comment: Your connection string was probably overriden when you copied your new website version on the server. Please check the connection string in web.config and see if it is valid.

Comment: "your new website version "? It is windows form application with local database add->new item->local database